# Why does ri not show TCPSocket class?

Tags: ruby, ri

I am trying to search `TCPSocket` ruby class documentation with `ri` but it shows nothing. Most of the gems are shown. I am using `rvm`, and `require 'socket'` works perfectly. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
gem rdoc --all
```

The documentation says:

```
        --all                        Generate RDoc/RI documentation for all
                                     installed gems
```

You can find these things out by typing:

```
gem help
```

or

```
gem help rdoc
```

at the command line.

You might want to throw on `--overwrite` to overwrite existing documentation.

Old versions of Ruby, around 1.8, didn't always have the core and/or std-lib documentation generated. There's a gem you can install that patches that, but I don't remember what it was right now.